# Not getting output for multiprocessing netmiko multiple devices

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Not getting output for multiple device connection using multiprocessing

I tried the following code:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from netmiko import ConnectHandler
import netmiko
import re
from datetime import datetime

def get_ip (input):
    return(re.findall(r'(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)', input))

def make_connection (ip, username, password):
                    device_connect = ConnectHandler(device_type='cisco_nxos', ip=ip, username=username, password=password)
                    output = device_connect.send_command("sh hostname")
                    print(output)
                    device_connect.disconnect()

def get_ips_nexus (file_name):
    for line in open(file_name, 'r').readlines():
        line = get_ip(line)
        for ip in line: 
            ips_nexus.append(ip)

ips_nexus = []
get_ips_nexus("ips-Copy.txt")
print(ips_nexus)
username = 'x.x.x.x'
password = 'xxxxxxxx'
startTime = datetime.now()
processes = []

for ip in ips_nexus:
            print('***********')
            print(ip)
            print('***********')
            p = mp.Process(target=make_connection, args=(ip, username, password))
            processes.append(p)
            p.start()
            print('!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!')

for p in processes:
    print(p)
    p.join()
print(datetime.now() - startTime
```

I am getting only print ip not the netmiko connected output of sh hostname.

I want to achieve multiple device connectivity using multiprocessing only!!!

Please help.

Comment: Any help is greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: First of all: Add the important `if __name__ == "__main__"` clause above your for-loop (`for ip in ips_nexus: (...)`) than say the output after that

Comment: Thats the output i got not the required output

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `if __name__ == "__main__"`clause! 
Add it above your for - loop for the processes:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":    # add this
    for ip in ips_nexus:
            print('***********')
            print(ip)
            print('***********')
            p = mp.Process(target=make_connection, args=(ip, username, password))
            processes.append(p)
            p.start()
            print('!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!')
```

### Why do I need it?

First of all: If you run a code of yours, the python interpreter imports it as a "**main**" file. You can try it, by adding `print(__name__)`. Anyway, if you start a new process with `multiprocessing`, than the python interpreter imports your code again and runs it as an extra-process **and** as a new skript!!! Well, if it reaches (in your case) this part again:

```py
p = mp.Process(target=make_connection, args=(ip, username, password))
```

it will start a new process again, imports it again and so on. In the end you are going to have an infinite loop, which starts your code every time as a new process! That's the reason why you have to add the (**important**) `if __name__ == "__main__"` clause! By adding this, `__name__` won't be `__main__` after the first call of a new process!

Comment: Hii ,I had that and am running the script ,script is running but the command output of output = device_connect.send_command("sh hostname") in function is not coming.

Comment: what do you get? An empty stirng? `None`? Can you please tell me it?

Comment: It's empty string!

Comment: Have you already tried it with the `expect_string` parameter? Otherwise I'm out of ideas.... sorry if I disappoint you... :( I hope somebody will help you better than me! Anyway, good luck!